# How to print lines of a document backwards in MASM32 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

My try:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;includem biblioteci, si declaram ce functii vrem sa importam
includelib msvcrt.lib
extern exit: proc
extern fgets:proc
extern fopen:proc
extern fclose:proc
extern printf:proc
extern getc:proc
extern ftell:proc
extern fseek:proc
extern fputs:proc
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;declaram simbolul start ca public - de acolo incepe executia
public start
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;sectiunile programului, date, respectiv cod
.data
;aici declaram date
s db 0
char dd 0
read db "r",0
write db "w",0
nume db "test2.txt",0
nume2 db "test3.txt",0
seek_end dd 2
i dd -1
.code

start:
    push offset read
    push offset nume
    call fopen
    add esp,8




    mov esi,eax


    push offset write
    push offset nume2
    call fopen
    add esp,8

    mov edi,eax

    push seek_end
    push 0
    push esi
    call fseek;
    add esp,12


    push esi
    call ftell
    add esp,4

    mov ebx,eax


    et:
        push esi
        call getc
        add esp,4

        ;mov eax,getc

        cmp eax,0ah

        jne et2

        et2:
            push 1
            push -1
            push esi
            call fseek
            add esp,12
            jmp cont
        et3:        
            push esi
            push 99
            push offset s
            call fgets
            add esp,12

            push edi
            push offset s
            call fputs
            add esp,8


            jmp et2

    cont:
        dec ebx
        cmp ebx,0
        jne et




    push 0
    call exit
end start
```

Comment: Your idea is good. Now implement it.

Comment: Sorry i didnt specify,I have problems with implementation.

Comment: I do not see an implementation. What have you tried so far?

Comment: How can i put for example a string in my array of strings ?

Comment: A couple comments on the code so far: 1) it doesn’t check the result of fopen, nor does it save it, which will be needed to call fgets more than once. 2) it doesn’t check the result of fgets, which is needed to detect the end of the input file.

Comment: You can either arrange for fgets to read the string directly into the next element of the array, or read it into the variable ‘string’ as you do now and then copy it into the next element of the array. Either way you have to track the array index and multiply by 50 to get the offset of the next member of the array.

Comment: I put above my second try using fseek ,but it doesn't work.